# ReactJS and Django with Axios - CSRF tokens and form data with POST requests

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, csrf, django-allauth

I've read through multiple examples and tried all of the code - for some strange reason none of it is working with my current project.

If I use postman I can add users without problem.

When I try to replicate my postman requests in React, it goes through just the same but no user details are saved to my Django database.

I've tried Django rest, researching and reading threads for two days.

Django Settings

```
"""
Django settings for demo_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '58u29^u@wy%90)%ni=u5muf1h(g@*el*o$q%nvnxji3*yg!1hl'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',


    'users',
    'pages',
]

# custom user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demo_project.urls'

# redirect urls for auth
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

# custom authentication backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True  # we want to store their email in django
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False  # we're not worried about user names

# CORS config
# CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
#     'localhost:5000',
#     '127.0.0.1:5000'
#     'localhost:3000',
#     '127.0.0.1:3000'
# )

# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
# CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
#     'xsrfheadername',
#     'xsrfcookiename',
#     'content-type',
#     "X-CSRFTOKEN"
# )

#CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'demo_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

React Frontend Form

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";
import cookie from "react-cookies";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "hihi@gmail.com",
      password1: "test123T",
      password2: "test123T"
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myUrl = "/accounts/signup/";
    var myData = "email=hihi%40gmail.com&password1=test123T&password2=test123T";
    axios
      .post(myUrl, myData, {
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": cookie.load("csrftoken"),
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "cache-control": "no-cache"
        }
        // other configuration there
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        alert("yeah!");
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        alert("oops");
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h3>This is going to be a register form hopefully</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            {/* {% csrf_token %} */}
            {/* {{ form.as_p }} */}

            <input
              placeholder="email"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              type="email"
              name="email"
            />
            <input
              placeholder="pw1"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              type="password"
              name="password1"
            />
            <input
              placeholder="pw2"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              type="password"
              name="password2"
            />

            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
          </form>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Proxy in Package json

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

My request headers and form data come through no worries

Request headers

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 60
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: csrftoken=pw59YcUID3RjZOOmcJlIUGNv1sBZQlRvX1hcNOkNVzMOEl0ETRUeZkTCU0lnVO1s; sessionid=17j037bo4oju0v6jprpkuv6x26m0eajt
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken: pw59YcUID3RjZOOmcJlIUGNv1sBZQlRvX1hcNOkNVzMOEl0ETRUeZkTCU0lnVO1s
```

Form data

```
email: hihi@gmail.com
password1: test123T
password2: test123T
```

My backend used to error saying there's no CSRF token present, but that error no longer occurs.

I also hit an obstacle where my frontend would get 'forbidden' but this no longer happens.

When I check my Django users DB, no user has been added :(

If I fire up postman, I can add users without problem.

Postman info

```
POST /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
X-CSRFToken: F8MuraVaDK3tUDwD39lVPthQgdkL4HPm
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d34b79e6-fd5b-44a2-9ed0-74d28fee882e
email=test%40gmail.compassword1=test123Tpassword2=test123T
```

I'm starting to get quite worn out on getting this going. So I'm hoping some amazing human out there will help to unblock me.

If you wish to clone / pull the repo let me know.

Comment: That is not the way you submit post data specially for user data which contains private things like email address and password. Also you don't need csrftoken. You should use tokens built for api requests and you should send the user data as post not as GET parameter.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but I am using post with Axios (not get). This is a non production app, I'm just trying to get React + Django + Social Auth up and running. If I remove CSRF token it returns 'forbidden'. Do you have a working example I can refer to? Thanks

Comment: Can you add your django rest view maybe?